# properly iterate through key value pair in angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I am getting the below json  response from server

```js
{"errors":{"email":["is invalid"],"password":["can't be blank"]}}
```

and I set it in controller to a scope named "errors" and am using it in my view

This is my view

```
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="errors" ng-repeat="error in errors">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in error">{{key}} {{error[key]}}</li>
</div>
```

The issue is that its showing the arrays of the values as well. How to properly loop through so that it wont show the values with the array symbol and quotes around them.

This is what am getting now

```
email ["is invalid"]
password ["can't be blank"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value`'s are in fact arrays with one item, so use `value[0]`  :

```html
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" ng-show="errors" ng-repeat="error in errors">
   <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in error">{{ key }} {{ value[0] }}</li>
</div>
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/0dOM0ZUCKXFXX2Y2a7a3?p=preview**

Comment: worked like charm..was fiddling with it for quite some time now..Thank you so much..